How to correctly apply the Runge-Kutta method to solve a system of differential equations?
Suppose I have the following system of differential equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
y'_{1} (t) = y_{2}(t) - y_{1}(t) \\
y'_{2}(t) = -y_{1}(t)y_{2}(t)
\end{cases}
$$
with the initial conditions:
$$
y_{1}(0) = 1,\ y_{2}(0) = 2
$$
I would like to compute $y_{1}(1)$ and $y_2(1)$ using a single step of the Runge-Kutta method with the following Butcher tableau:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
0 & 0 & \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
  & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
$$

I've started by writing out my system of equations in vector form:
$\overrightarrow {y}(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}(t) \\
y_{2}(t)
\end{bmatrix}
$,
$\overrightarrow {f}(t, \overrightarrow {y}(t)) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{2}(t) - y_{1}(t) \\
-y_{1}(t)y_{2}(t)
\end{bmatrix}
$, and
$\overrightarrow {y}(0) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}
$
Now I am solving the following system:
$$
\overrightarrow {y}'(t) = \overrightarrow {f}(t, \overrightarrow y(t))
$$
IIUC, this is how you build the solution:
$$
\overrightarrow {y}_{1} = \overrightarrow {y}_{0} + \frac{1}{2} \overrightarrow {k_{1}} + \frac{1}{2} \overrightarrow {k_{2}}
$$
where $k_{1}$:
$$
\overrightarrow {k_{1}} = h \cdot \overrightarrow {f}(0 + 0 \cdot h, \overrightarrow {y}(0)) = 
\overrightarrow {f}(0, \overrightarrow {y}(0)) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 - 1 \\
-1 \cdot 2
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $k_{2}$:
$$
\overrightarrow{k_{2}} = h \cdot \overrightarrow{f}(0 + 1 \cdot h, \overrightarrow{y}(0) + 1 \cdot \overrightarrow{k_{1}}) = \overrightarrow{f}(1, \overrightarrow{y}(0) + \overrightarrow{k_{1}}) = \overrightarrow{f}(1, \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix})
$$
I think I've got it right so far (I'd appreciate the notation edits as I'm not really sure I got everything down correctly).

Now, I don't know how to compute this:
$$
\overrightarrow{f}(1, \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix})
$$
According to my understanding, this would lead to evaluating $y_{1}(1)$ and $y_{2}(1)$ as part of my computation. But these are the values I'm trying to compute with my method! Therefore, I must have done something wrong.

What you got in $\vec y(0)+\vec k_1$ is a first approximation of the value at $\vec y(1)$. But it is the Euler value, first order. With $\vec k_2$ and the composition formula you compute a better approximation of order 2.
So forget the context for a moment and just compute the function value of $\vec f$.

So, $\overrightarrow k_{2} = (-2, 0)^{T}$?

Yes, simply that. Of course that means that $k_1+k_2=0$, so that $y(1)\approx y(0)$. For more accurate results you need a smaller step size. This ODE and method could be implemented in Excel or similar, if you have no BASIC or Python available.

$\overrightarrow {k_{1}} +  \overrightarrow {k_{2}} = (-1, -2)^{T}$ according to my calculations. Precision of the result is not important to me at this time, only the correct procedure since this is an exam question.

Yes, that is correct, I was reading too fast and taking some close prominent vector. But still, with changes the same size as the components the step size is likely much too large.
